# Saving custom datetime in the same format as created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a Rails 3.2 web app.
In this app got a model called Timereport. In this model I got an attribute called reported_at. This used so that that the user reporting the time can select a custom reported_at date to be used.

On the server side I save it like this:

```
report.reported_at = DateTime.parse(params[:reported_at])
```

When I use the console I see the date is saved like this:

```
#<Timereport id: 1583, account_id: 24, created_at: "2014-07-01 10:30:16", updated_at: "2014-07-01 10:30:16", by_admin: true, timereportable_id: 46, timereportable_type: "Project", reported_at: "2014-07-01 00:00:00">
```

When I get the attribute in the console I get:

```
t.reported_at
=> Mon, 30 Jun 2014 19:00:00 CDT -05:00
```

But when I get the updated_at I get:

```
t.created_at
=> Tue, 01 Jul 2014 05:30:16 CDT -05:00
```

How can I save the reported_at in the same format as created_at so that it behaves the same way?

Thankful for all help!

Comment: Is the problem that a reported_at that on input at the console appears as 'Mon, 30 Jun 2014 19:00:00 CDT -5.00' becomes 'Mon, 30 Jun 2014 00:00:00 CDT -5.00' when the Timereport is saved? Is so what is the output of Timereport.first.column_for_attribute(:reported_at).sql_type

Comment: The output for the command is "timestamp without time zone" same as for created_at. Is that good?

Comment: It demonstrates that the database field configuration is the problem. I see from another comment, that you've solved the problem. Out of interest, what database are you using?

Comment: But is the fields really the problem? Created_at is Rails "default" and it has the same type. Well, I think I solved it by adding time to the date.

Comment: Also I am using Postgresql at Heroku.

Comment: You're right and my comment was wrong. You not passing a time into the field would explain the problem. I hope my input was still some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the reported_at field is a datetime field in the database.

Then rather than giving a text field for users to enter the date and time, use a [datetime_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/datetime_select) element. This will generate a selection tool that submits the datetime elements in a format that ActiveRecord understands and can convert into the correct format.

You will then not have to DateTime.parse(params[:reported_at]), but just load the data from params in the normal way.

Comment: The reported_at field is a datetime field. Also I am using the Datepicker jQuery plugin. But still the same issue.

Comment: Then I am confused. "Mon, 30 Jun 2014 19:00:00 CDT -05:00" looks to me to be in exactly the same format as "Tue, 01 Jul 2014 05:30:16 CDT -05:00". Can you please explain in what way the format is different.

Comment: I think I found the issue. I was not saving the date with a time attached to it. I.e. I saved 2014-07-01 instead of 2014-07-01 12:20:22